# How to show Byte[] data in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

For showing `Byte[]` data in `GridView`, I have used below code

```
DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("Bytes", typeof(string));
```

I like to know if it's correct or not?

Complete code is like below:

```
Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("Bytes", typeof(string));

dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("File Name", typeof(string));
DataColumn dc2 = 1new DataColumn("File Size", typeof(string));
DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Content Type", typeof(string));
DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("Bytes", typeof(string));

dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
dt.Columns.Add(dc4);

dr = dt.NewRow();

dr["File Name"] = FileName;

if (size > 0)
  dr["File Size"] = size.ToString() + " KB";
else
  { dr["File Size"] = fileObj.Length.ToString() + " Bytes"; }

dr["Content Type"] = contenttype;
dr["Bytes"] = bytes;


dt.Rows.Add(dr);
GridViewEfile.DataSource = dt;
GridViewEfile.DataBind();
```

Comment: What do you mean "is it correct". You tell us, is it correct?

Comment: actually i do not know what i have to use for new DataColumn("Bytes", typeof(string));typeof(string) is correct or typeof(binary) or something else

Comment: Correct for doing what?

Comment: after uploading files and showing them in gridview , i want to use byte data of each record of gridview, now i can get file name & size & type of file for each record but for byte data i have problem, how i can get that for each record by using for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)

Comment: But what do you want to show. "The file" is not an easy way to display.. Do you want to show the *contents* of the file, a thumbnail, an icon of the file type. You can't just blurp out an array of bytes in a GUI, it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: just i am looking for just 1 way for keeping binary data of each file has been uploaded, because i want to save all of information of files has been uploaded (size,type,data) in database.

Comment: Now you mention saving to database. Do you want to "show" the byte array, or save it in the database? You need to clarify what the actual problem is you're facing. Does your code work or not, and if not, what is the expected outcome and what actually happens?

Comment: We are confused, what you want exactly show in DataGrid , Files or info about files, is there a problem if yes then what is exactly ?